# CSS code completion as in Firebug

Tags: major-mode, completion

One of the convenient features of in-browser inspectors like Firebug is that it is so easy to tweak CSS stylesheets.  As you type in the attribute position, all possible attributes are shown in a dropdown list and can be picked from.  On the right hand side of a declaration, input is restricted to only valid values (which for some attributes is really just a very small number of values).

I'm looking for a CSS mode that makes editing CSS stylesheets easier by offering sensible contextual completion suggestions, or that even restricts my inputs to only valid values.  Does anything like that already exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/) provides slightly better results than `auto-complete` using the bundled `company-css` backend.

You get completion of property names (up-to-date with the current state of CSS3, AFAIK), and *some* completion of property values, where they are simple, like a fixed set of options.

Comment: I've grown quite attached to auto-complete mode, not least because it's an official part of Emacs.  Maybe I should just extend the ac-sources for css-mode with whatever company-mode offers over auto-complete at the moment.

Comment: It's absolutely *not* an official part of Emacs.

Comment: Dmitry: you are right, I was mistaken.  I remembered reading about autocomplete and company on the emacs-devel mailinglist (where rms asked about what popular packages are not yet included with Emacs) and I misremembered the information given there.  Thanks for correcting me.  I shall try company-mode.

Comment: I'm using `company-mode` now, but completion of property values is elusive.  Completion for property names is good, though.

Comment: @rekado "completion of property values is elusive" Feel free to create an issue with your complaints. But indeed, implementing smart completion logic for values is hard.

Answer (score 4):

[`auto-complete`](http://auto-complete.org/) offers contextual completion for values of CSS properties:

[image: auto-complete in css-mode]

The default setup for `auto-complete` (which will also enable completion in `css-mode` buffers) is:

```el
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

If you want to enable `auto-complete` for `css-mode` buffers *only*, add the following to your init-file:

```el
(require 'auto-complete-config)

(defun css-setup-ac ()
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
  (ac-css-mode-setup)
  (auto-complete-mode 1))

(add-hook 'css-mode-hook #'css-setup-ac)
```

I don't know of any existing modes that *restrict* property values to valid values.

Comment: There is no completion for property *names*, though; I only see completion for *values*.